# How is the 'equal' template function implemented? (predicate version)

Tags: c++, stl-algorithm

I am working through the book "Accelerated C++" and one of the exercises require us to emulate the 'equal' function in the  header and so far I have implemented the simple version which takes three parameters as follows:

```
template <class iterType1, class iterType2>
bool cequal(iterType1 begin, iterType1 end, iterType2 e){

    while(begin != end){
        if(!(*begin == *e))
            return false;
        ++begin;
        ++e;
    }
    return true;
}
```

and the second version which can accept a fourth parameter...

```
template <class iterType1, class iterType2, class boolPred>
bool cequal(iterType1 begin, iterType1 end, iterType2 e, boolPred pred){

    while(begin != end){
        if(!pred(*begin, *e))
            return false;
        ++begin;
        ++e;
    }
    return true;
}
```

My question is, is this the ideal way to do it? or are these two functions mergable?

Answer (score 3):

The first version can call the second version, passing an [equal_to](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/functional/equal_to/) object as the last parameter.  <strike>Or you can just set that as a default parameter.</strike> I take that back.  I can't actually figure out a way to have a default argument for a function template.  I can't even figure out how to re-use the code in the overload solution without using a c++0x feature(decltype).

```
template <class iterType1, class iterType2>
bool cequal(iterType1 begin, iterType1 end, iterType2 e){
    return cequal(begin, end, e, std::equal_to<decltype(*begin)>());
}
```

Comment: The problem with `equal_to` is that it expects the 2 operands to have the same type, whereas his function has 2 different types for its operands.

Comment: @Blindy: His function has different types for it's iterators, but that doesn't mean the types of elements wouldn't be the same.  I think it's unlikely that you would want to compare two different types anyway, and this will raise an error if you try to.  I don't really see that as a problem.  If that is what he wants, he can of course use a different function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to merge them, you could provide a default predicate for the last parameter that only calls `operator==` on the inputs.

edit: an example would be:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct eqpred
{
  bool operator(T1 &a, T2 &b) { return a==b; }
}

template <class iterType1, class iterType2, class boolPred=eqpred>
bool cequal(iterType1 begin, iterType1 end, iterType2 e, boolPred pred){

    while(begin != end){
        if(!pred(*begin, *e))
            return false;
        ++begin;
        ++e;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I thought about that but I don't know the syntax to set the default parameter to == operator

Comment: Does this work?  This will require you to explicitly pass a `boolPred` as the last argument, and IIRC you can't give default arguments in function templates.

Comment: @templatetypedef, love your name lol; I think it should work, although my C++ is rusty these days.

Answer (score 0):

Those two functions aren't just mergeable, they're almost exactly the same, line for line.

I could expand and do it all for you, but that would be a bit of a spoiler.