# Default templated parameters in function templates

Tags: c++, templates, default-value

I was answering [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731007/how-is-the-equal-template-function-implemented-predicate-version/4731084#4731084) question.  And I realized that I ran my mouth off when I didn't know what I was talking about.

So my question is this.  Is it possible to merge these functions in to one? (don't worry that this is an exact duplicate of a function that already exists, I'm just using it as an example)

```
template <class iterType1, class iterType2, class boolPred>
bool equal(iterType1 begin, iterType1 end, iterType2 e, boolPred pred){

    while(begin != end){
        if(!pred(*begin, *e))
            return false;
        ++begin;
        ++e;
    }
    return true;
}

template <class iterType1, class iterType2>
bool equal(iterType1 begin, iterType1 end, iterType2 e){
    return equal(begin, end, e, std::equal_to<decltype(*begin)>());
}
```

Furthermore, is re-using the code from the first in the second even possible without using C++0x features(decltype).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to merge these functions in to one?

Sadly, no.  You can't have a default template argument for a function template parameter  and default function arguments cannot be used to deduce template arguments.

> Is re-using the code from the first in the second even possible without using C++0x features?

Yes:  you can use `std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type`.